# Expressjs - Use middleware inside middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I would like to use a middleware for validating requests based on a raml file.
What my code looks like:

```
// require   
let resources = require('osprey-resources');
let errorHandler = require('request-error-handler');
let handler = require('osprey-method-handler');

// create express instance
let app = express();

// ramlObj obtained by raml2obj.parse(myPath).then()
let router = resources(ramlObj.resources,
    function (method, path) {

        // get the method type : get/post/etc
        let methodType = method.method.toUpperCase();

        // provide a function (controller) for this path
        return controllers.provideController(methodType, path);
    }
);

// osprey-router middelware , created by osprey-resources
app.use('/v1', router);

// error Handler middelware
app.use(errorHandler(responder, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, customMessages));

// What I want:

// routes middelware
app.use('/v1', custom_middleware(method, methodType, path), router);
```

where `custom_middleware` use `osprey-method-handler` inside with all parameters I provided to him.
I tried connect without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example you need to use a partial function to allow `req`, `res` and `next` to be sent to your `custom_middleware` function.

An example using lodash:

```
// Route
app.use('/v1', _.partialRight(custom_middleware, method, methodType, path), router);

// Function
custom_middleware(req, res, next, method, methodType, path) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know lodash is great for functional programming so I will give it a try.

Comment: Just a question, osprey-method-handler use inside its code next() call .... So , what happend if custom_middleware doesn't have to do next() (but rely on osprey-method-handler)?

Comment: just tested ... , the next  middleware (router) cannot work if I don't receive the result of osprey-method-handler result ....

Comment: You need to call `next()` to signal to the middleware that it is done and to move on to the next operation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my code since the last and find another way to do that : https://www.npmjs.com/package/compose-middleware : no problem for next call with this